# Does "Do this if any of As are B" and "Do this if some of As are B" means the same?

Tags: meaning, quantifiers

Does these two sentences have the same meaning?

> 1. Do this if any of As are B.
> 2. Do this if some of As are B.

I would say yes, but I am not sure; if so, is one prefered over another? The second sounds better to me, but I think in mathematical and technical literature one more often ecounters the first.

Comment: Welcome to ELL! +1 Good question. (You don't need *of* in your examples, by the way. You can just say *if some As are B*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They mean the same.

> "If some of the As are Bs"

suggest that you are expecting either none or a plural amount:

> If some of the lines have comments, take a sample of the comments and check for grammatical accuracy.

But using "any" could mean you are expecting perhaps only one.

> If any of the lines have comments award one mark for use of a comment.

But you could have switched some and any in these examples and there would be no ambiguity or loss of meaning.